# Regex to match links

Tags: regex, string, match, lookup, regex-greedy

I am trying to match a string that starts with:

```
http://www.xxxx.la/wallpaper/
```

and end with:

```
">
```

Here is what I got, but it does not work:

```
/\bhttp:\/\/www\.xxxx\.la\/wallpaper\/\w+\"\>\b/
```

Comment: *it does not work* without actual description what error you get makes the question unclear. Also, *up to `>`* hints at parsing HTML with regex - you could avoid the issue in the first place if you used a correct tool for the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` matches word characters, meaning letters, numbers, or underscores. It does *not* match spaces.

I think you need instead: `/http:\/\/www\.xxxx\.la\/wallpaper\/.+\"\>/` (replacing `\w` with `.`).

Answer (score 1):

`\b` represents boundaries between a word. It might not be the beginning or the end of the string. For the beginning, use `^`. And for the end, use `$`. So your regex will be this:

```
/^http:\/\/www\.xxxx\.la\/wallpaper\/\S+\"\>$/
```

I prefer `\S` instead of `\w`. I am afraid `\w` character range are too limited.